# Testing using Jest and Enzyme: how to navigate React Router DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write an integration test for a React app created as part of a Udemy course. The app is using `react-router-dom`, and I want to simulate clicking on a `Link`, which should change the route, and then test something on the screen corresponding to the new route.

I was able to `mount` the App component using Enzyme, but I can't seem to navigate successfully in the test environment:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Root from 'src/Root'
import App from 'src/components/App'

it('navigates to the post screen when clicking the post button', () => {
  const wrapped = mount(
    // My Root component wraps the children with a Redux Provider
    <Root initialState={{ auth: true }}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Root>
  )

  // Click on the post button
  wrapped.find('a.post-link').simulate('click')
  // Update the component, hoping that the navigation would take effect
  wrapped.update()
  // Expecting to find a CommentBox, which is what is rendered by the '/post' Route
  // Unfortunately, it seems that the navigation either didn't occur or is still ongoing, as the test fails: there are 0 CommentBox components found.
  expect(wrapped.find('CommentBox').length).toEqual(1)
})
```

This is my App component, for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import CommentBox from 'src/components/CommentBox'
import CommentList from 'src/components/CommentList'
import * as actions from 'src/actions'

class App extends Component {
  renderButton() {
    const { auth, changeAuth } = this.props
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => changeAuth(!auth)}
        className="auth-button"
      >
        Sign {auth ? 'out' : 'in'}
      </button>
    )
  }

  renderHeader() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link className="post-link" to="/post">Post a comment</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          {this.renderButton()}
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderHeader()}
        <Route path="/post" component={CommentBox} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={CommentList} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { auth: state.auth }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App)
```

Comment: Are you sure the button was found?

Comment: try this -> component.find("[className='post-link']").simulate("click");

Comment: The button is definitely found:
`console.log(wrapped.find('a.post-link').html())`
console.log src/__tests__/integrations.test.js:49
      <a class="post-link" href="/post">Post a comment</a>